# Ajax Vs url in src of script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i'm wondering what's the difference between these two ways of calling an url, starting from the point that i don't need any response from it:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mysuperwebsite.com/page.php?var1=something&var2=somethingelse">
</script>
```

and

```html
<script>
try
{
 jQuery.ajax(
 {
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://www.mysuperwebsite.com/page.php",
  data:
  {
   'var1': 'something',
   'var2': 'somethingelse'
  },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
 });
}
catch(error){}
</script>
```

I've always used the jQuery way but i'm now asking myself why wouldn't be ok the first way. There are surely differences i don't know.

Thanks

Comment: They're totally different! The first loads (and runs)a JS file, the second expects a JSON response (and in the code you posted appears to do nothing with the result, while suppressing any errors).

Comment: wouldn't the first way call the php page in the same way? I mean, the php page sees  the get parameters passed in the same way, does not return anything and technically the script tag will not import anything. Am i wrong?

Comment: Well it'll make a request to the server, which will run the PHP script - but it'll expect the result to be valid Javascript, and try to run it as such. If it's not valid JS you'll get a syntax error. Meanwhile the Ajax code is expecting a JSON response. Javascript and JSON are not the same thing! So which approach is appropriate depends entirely on what that PHP script actually does.

Answer (score -1):

If i'm not mistaken using src= will refresh your page when response is received.